# Why does the parameter $0 give me only the basename instead of full path after converting x-shellscript to x-executable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

My problem here is that the parameter `$0` gives the same result as `${0##*/}`, and that happens after converting the x-shellscript to x-executable using the SHC program!

OS: Debiab-8.2-jessie
SHC version: 3.8.7
cmd used: `shc -f script.bash`

The compiled script.x resides in a extra bin path (not known by sudo).
**Note** I've created a hello world program to print the parametr $0, and it always gives me the basename!

My scriptFile contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
((!EUID)) || exec sudo "$0"
# shellcode ...
```

When I execute it, I get this:

> sudo: scriptName: command not found

After checking out I found that the parameter `$0` is the same as `${0##*/}` or `$(basename $0)` inside an x-executable!

How do I deal with that without putting an absolute path inside the script? Or is there something I should know when I'm compiling shell to x-executable using SHC?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by “x-shellscript” and “x-executable”?

Comment: @Gilles bash script and binary executable .

Comment: But `$0` is bash syntax, not something you have in an executable. Are you using some kind of “compiler” for shell scripts? That's very unusual and basically never useful. And if you are, it's absolutely the sort of thing we can't guess, you need to say what tool you're using and how. And tell us how you're executing the script, too.

Comment: converting bash script to binary executable using shc program ! sorry for lake of infos , i'm going to edit the question :)

Comment: read the manual for `sudo`, you can configure it to allow specified command to be run as specified user, **without a password**. (because I am guessing from your code that you are trying to hide a password it at executable, because you think that if you can not extract it then I don't know how to run `strings`)

Comment: @richard no not that , i'm just trying to understand , try , check stuff :) and i'm aware that a binary executable code can be seen using ` env SHELLOPTS=verbose ./script.x ` !

Comment: I do not get that result here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why SHC?

First of all, why are you using SHC, given your "hobbyist" motivations? Here is an excerpt from their own description:

> Upon execution, the compiled binary will decrypt and execute the code with the shell -c option. Unfortunatelly, it will not give you any speed improvement as a real C program would.
>
> The compiled binary will still be dependent on the shell specified in the first line of the shell code (i.e. #!/bin/sh), thus shc does not create completely independent binaries.
>
> **SHC's main purpose is to protect your shell scripts from modification or inspection.**

- **My opinion** (I'll keep it sort of brief): Even if your motivation is the stated "main purpose" of preventing modifications, a mildly determined person can still recover (and, hence, modify) the original script! SHC essentially provides [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), which is an oft-derided strategy when used as a *primary* means of security. If this doesn't sound helpful, then I'd recommend ditching SHC and simply using shell scripts as the vast majority of others do. If you need real security for your shell scripts, I'd suggest asking a specific question about that, without SHC or "compilers".

### The specific $0 problem

I downloaded SHC 3.8.9 from [this page](http://utappia.org/how-to-encrypt-convert-shell-script-to-binary-executable.html) just to try this out.

I was not able to reproduce the problem, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, world. My name is \`$0'"
```

#### Test run

```
$ ./shc -f my_test.bash
$ ~/path/to/my_test.bash.x

Hello, world. My name is `~/path/to/my_test.bash.x'
```

So, clearly, our systems differ. I can try to update this answer if you post more details about your operating system,  version of SHC, and *specific* shell script and `shc` commandline you used to "compile" it.

### Why do you need the path?

Why does your script need to know its path? Are you storing files with the script? Does it "default" to operate on the directory it was run in if the user doesn't specify? Whether these things are good ideas or not is a matter of opinion, but knowing your motivations might be helpful in narrowing down this answer.

### How to fetch the current directory

The `pwd` command fetches the current directory. In many cases, you can assemble the full path of your script (assuming it was run with an explicit relative path) with something like:

```
realname="`pwd`/$0"
```

... which would result in a value like:

```
/path/to/script/./yourscript.bash.x
```

The extra `./` just means "current directory", so while it might be cosmetically unfortunate, it will not negatively affect the result.

If the script is simply in your `$PATH`, then you would need to use `which` instead of `pwd`, but we're already getting beyond the scope of the original question, here, so I'll conclude with a simple mention that determining pathnames can be a tricky process, especially if you need to do so in a secure manner, so that would best be left for another question with a specific problem statement along these lines.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time ! i'm going to add infos about os and shc version ...

Comment: To get `$PWD` just use `$PWD` - it's not prone to command sub issues, either. And if you want a physical path there, do `cd -P .` first.

Comment: @mikeserv Indeed, since `pwd` implementations often just read from `$PWD` by default, I support your comment. Your comment also sort of highlights more of the reason why dealing with paths usually deserves special attention&mdash;more than I can reasonably provide without a more detailed question.

Comment: current directory is not what he wants, he wans the directory that has the compiled file

Comment: @Jasen I addressed that, somewhat thoroughly.

Comment: @younes Thanks for the additional information in the question! Beyond what I've already suggested, the best advice I can offer is to really think about your bigger design: do you really need a binary file (much harder to distribute than a script!) and do you need to put it outside of `$PATH`/sudo's awareness (yet have it call `sudo` itself? why not just use sudo's command aliases?) I fear with your current design you will just create grief for yourself and have *worse* security as compared to using standard tools, which I know you're still learning. (Keep asking questions! You'll get there.)

Comment: current directory is in general absolutely no use at all when trying to locate a script

Comment: @Jasen Well then, in general, absolute paths in `$0` are "absolutely no use" either! :-) The point of my answer that I think you've missed is that the whole *idea* of trying to derive paths from `$0` is tricky (in technical and security terms). As I said in my answer, the topic deserves its own question with a more detailed look at what younes needs to accomplish there, as this question is already well outside typical best practices, thus "standard" methods and guesswork aren't likely to lead to good outcomes. You've gotten hung up on the `pwd` thing, which I might clarify later (thanks!).

Comment: dear @type_outcast i just want to say that your question made things clear to me , even i'm aware of many stuff you explained ! your "hello world" test makes me think that something wrong with my debian installtion , as i said i'm hobbyist , i keep trying stuff ,  i'm not interset in compiling shell to binary executable , i'm just trying to understand things .... ! at the end i'll say that your question is pretty nice for me even if it contains only a link to google , indeed it's better than a "close" vote by negatives , or making fun of me when i pointed to something by its mimetype ! Thanks.

Comment: for everyone will read this question/answer , later i installed a fresh os 'kali-linux-sana-2.0' with 'shc version 3.8.7'  , and as @type_outcast said i wasn't able to reproduce the problem ! which means i had something wrong with my whole old installation (Debian-jessie) , as conclusion my question is useless but the answer is helpful for other searchers.

Answer (score -1):

it seems to be because bash (and/or ld.so) doesn't put the full name of the executable in argv[0] when it locates a binary by path search.  if you specify the directory when you run it (instead of relying on path) it gets the right name.

Comment: The point is, `argv[0]`/`$0` may have no relation to the program name (let alone the executable path) *at all,* which I may yet work into my answer. One can use any number of standard utilities/languages to trivially do the equivalent of `execl("/hacked/path/modified_script", "/path/to/original_script", (char *)0);` which would fool your method of using the full pathname so the script gets the *wrong* name instead of "the right name," as you suggested. That's why I strongly questioned the use of `$0`/paths in my answer, especially since the question has fairly deep roots in security.

Comment: that's a good point, expecially when combined with passwordless `sudo` it's ripe for exploit. (work that in too)

Comment: no if you're a script and executed via "shebang" $0 is guaranteed to refer to the file  (else how could the interpreter open the script file to run it).  if you're SHC it's not shebang, and $0 is something else.

Comment: from the propdecf of the called process, $0 and argv[0] are not the same thing. in this case argv[0] is `bash` and $0 is the filename of the script (with suffifient path information)